# How to invoke conan in docker container by jenkins? error Failed to execute script conan

Tags: jenkins, cmake, conan

Using Docker as a build environment, My jenkinsfile starting specified docker container and invoking CMake which trigger build process using conan and so on. Unfortunately pipeline failed with the following output:

```
-- Conan: checking conan executable
-- Conan: Found program /usr/bin/conan
-- Conan: Version found [148] Failed to execute script conan
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conan/conans/conan.py", line 11, in <module>
 File "conan/conans/conan.py", line 7, in run
 File "conan/conans/client/command.py", line 2151, in main
 File "conan/conans/client/conan_api.py", line 222, in factory
 File "conan/conans/client/conan_api.py", line 234, in __init__
 File "conan/conans/client/migrations.py", line 26, in __init__
 File "conan/conans/client/cache/cache.py", line 78, in __init__
File "conan/conans/client/cache/cache.py", line 150, in config
  File "conan/conans/util/files.py", line 190, in save
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/.conan/conan.conf'
-- Conan executing: /usr/bin/conan install . -s build_type=Release -s compiler=clang -s compiler.version=10 -s compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11 -g=cmake --build=missing
[176] Failed to execute script conan
 Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I do not know what the problem is. If I start container and build it manually it works.
If I create it manually then I am getting following error:

```
Conan: Version found ERROR: Can't write version file in /.conan/version.txt
```

Comment: The error message says the file `/.conan/conan.conf` doesn't exist. Does it? Perhaps this should be `~/.conan/conan.conf`?

Comment: @squareskittles as far as I understood,  jenkins has no write permission on root directories, even if I create /.conan/conan.conf manually, conan cannot write it. I don't know how to handle it

Comment: @full_steak_developer which docker image are you running? Conan provides some stable docker images:  https://github.com/conan-io/conan-docker-tools. Anyway, you could use a custom Conan folder by passing CONAN_USER_HOME (https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/env_vars.html#conan-user-home)

Comment: @uilianries I am running a custom image where I installed other tools. The point I didn't get: When I attach in the docker container and run simply CMake to build my project is working, where I ran as root. The point here some permissions. Jenkins user is not allowed to access root directories. I guess this should be solved somehow :/

Comment: @full_steak_developer now I get. Conan, by default will use the home dir to put its folder. As you are running as root, it should be /root I think, but for some reason it's using the root level /. Anyway, I recommend you using an alternative path by the env var CONAN_USER_HOME. It could be in /tmp, as I supposed your container is temporary, only for building propose. Otherwise, you can try /root or /opt for instance.

Comment: @uilianries I am exactly trying this out by writing `ARG CONAN_USER_HOME=/tmp/` in my dockerfile. Till now no success or Am I doing incorrect way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following environment variable to my jenkinsfile. Then it simply works!. I was trying to define env variables in docker container that was my fail

```
  environment {
        CONAN_USER_HOME = "${env.WORKSPACE}/"
        CONAN_NON_INTERACTIVE = 1
    }
```

Comment: CONAN_USE_ALWAYS_SHORT_PATHS is only for Windows, if you are creating docker images for Linux, it has no effect.